# what is the total no of resources can we create in single cloud formation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I am using AWS cloud formation template which will create some dev environment but can anyone help me the find out the no of resources can we create in one single cloud formation template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use to create 200 resources in single cloud formation template